# eclipse wizard selectable items out of sight

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, liferay-ide

The problem is that, for instance, if i want to create a new project from a plugin-wizard and there are 5 selectable voices, the fifth voice isn't either visible or selectable.
I'm working on fedora-20.
There are solutions to make visible and selectable this kind of voices?

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information here. Show us the relevant code.

Comment: There isn't any code. See the linked image. http://s14.postimg.org/sf0gdx4zl/Screenshot_from_2014_03_22_12_47_58.png   after "layout template" there will be other 3 voices, but aren't neither visible or selectable

Comment: So this is a question about the Liferay plugins?

Comment: All plugins have the se problem,  i've picked liferay plugin as example

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (eclipse, new, project, creation, wizard) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desktop resolution is too small. These wizards aren't designed for low resolution. The main composite of the wizards is not automatically scrollable and that's why you cannot see the other options.

Try to change the window appearance of fedora. Changing the font size of GNOME/KDE might solve the problem.